# Find which columns of a table are referenced by which tables, Stored Procedures, Views and Functions

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am studying a C# code and SQL 2008 database, developed by an independent software vendor, and trying to optimise the code.

There is a table with very high no. of columns, many of which may not be required apparently. I want to know which columns of this table are referenced by other tables, stored procedures, views, or functions, so that I can delete the unwanted columns.

I am not an expert in SQL 2008; so if there are any inbuilt tools or queries, will appreciate step by step instructions.

Using View Dependencies, I can only find out which other objects refer to this table, but it does not tell the columns of this table which are referred by other objects.

Answer (score 2):

Select the table name and then press ALT+ F1, It will give you details of columns which is referenced to other tables and views in SQL Server.

Moreover, You can use below query for Keyword searching.you need to write  desired column name in @Keyword variable,then below query will give you all object details where that keyword is used.This will help you.

```
set nocount on 
declare @Keyword as varchar(200)
set @Keyword = 'Column name'

SELECT DISTINCT
    name, 
    CASE o.xtype 
        WHEN 'S' THEN 'System Stored Proc'
        WHEN 'F' THEN 'Foreign Key'
        WHEN 'U' THEN 'Table'
        WHEN 'V' THEN 'View'
        WHEN 'P' THEN 'Stored Proc'
        WHEN 'PK' THEN 'Primary Key'
        WHEN 'TR' THEN 'Trigger'
        WHEN 'UQ' THEN 'Unique Index'
        WHEN 'D' THEN 'Default'
        WHEN 'FN' THEN 'User Defined Function'
        ELSE 'Unknown'
    END, 
    text 
FROM
    sysobjects o left join syscomments c ON c.id = o.id
WHERE
    text LIKE '%' + @Keyword + '%' 
OR  name LIKE '%' + @Keyword + '%'
```

Comment: I pressed Alt + F1 on table name. Nothing happened? Moreover, using the above query, I will have to run the query approx. more than 100 times (once for each column). Is there a better way to identify all used columns in a table?

Comment: Also, the query will probably identify all objects where a particular column name is used; if multiple tables have identical column names, then it may not be useful.

Comment: ALT + F1 is working,you have to select table name and then press ALT+ F1,you might doing some mistake for the same.. And yes the query wont give you exact answer,I give it to you as an alternative !

Comment: I have pressed Alt + F1 several times after selecting table name in SQL Server Express Management Studio 2008. It is not working. May be any configuration required?

Comment: Yes, I am thinking the same ! Well I used it in SQL Server Express Management Studio 2008 as well as now in 2012 too.